# I have a <div> element which contains an image and <figcaption>. When I try to add the padding to the <figcaption> it does not work

Tags: css

I have the following code, but I can't figure out why the padding is not working when it should be pretty simple.

```css
 .img-caption {
        visibility:hidden;
        width:22%;
        height:435px;
        background-color:#f9f4e3;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        padding-left:2px;
    }
```

```html
<div class=img-div>
        <img class="image interpreter" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ffYO-4WQL.jpg">
        <figcaption class="img-caption interpreter-caption"><h3>Interpreter of Maladies</h3><p>Sit tempor amet dolor sanctus sed clita consetetur et justo, et et et gubergren lorem dolor ea dolor. Aliquyam sed.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus provident id aut tenetur, nam reprehenderit nesciunt, saepe iste animi perferendis ipsum recusandae praesentium? Aliquid nisi reiciendis at debitis est impedit.</p></figcaption>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `img-caption` is not visible. Therefore no padding or element can be seen. By changing the visability to visible via `visibility:visible;` you can see your figcaption and see that the padding is applied.

```css
.img-caption {
    visibility:visible;
    width:22%;
    height:435px;
    background-color:#f9f4e3;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class=img-div>
    <img class="image interpreter" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ffYO-4WQL.jpg">
    <figcaption class="img-caption interpreter-caption"><h3>Interpreter of Maladies</h3><p>Sit tempor amet dolor sanctus sed clita consetetur et justo, et et et gubergren lorem dolor ea dolor. Aliquyam sed.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus provident id aut tenetur, nam reprehenderit nesciunt, saepe iste animi perferendis ipsum recusandae praesentium? Aliquid nisi reiciendis at debitis est impedit.</p></figcaption>
    </div>
```